# How to align center without break the user experience?

Tags: html, css

I have a footer with links and you can see the [results here](https://jsfiddle.net/q33q8tng/):

**HTML**

```
<footer class="footer_outer">   
        <section class="footer">
            <p>&copy; bla bla bla</p><br>
            <p><span id="solen"><a href="#">xxxx</a></span>  <span id="solen"><a href="#">aaaa</a></span>  <span id="solen"><a href="#">cccccc</a></span>  <span id="solen"><a href="#">bbbbb</a></span>  <span id="solen"><a href="#">yyyy</a></span></p>

        </section><br>
    </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer_outer{width:100%;background-color:#eaeef2}.footer{border-top:1px solid #c7cbce;padding:.6em 0;width:960px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center}.footer p{font-size:.75em;color:#9c9c9c;font-size:14px; text-align:center;}#toTop{position:fixed;bottom:30px;cursor:pointer;right:20px;z-index:9999}#toTop:hover{opacity:.8}#solen{margin:10px; float:left}
```

This code has a small problem, the links are not aligned in the center of the page, to correct this I just delete the command `float:left` from div `#solen`.

But this is the problem, if I do that and resize the screen the links are very close to each others and this makes it difficult for the user click on links, because breaks the user experience (if I run this code on google test speed I will receive a note of 93/100 on user experience, instead of 100/100 without deleting the `float:left`).

How can I fix this without breaking the user experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need modification in your CSS and need to have HTML division tag :

```
<footer class="footer_outer">   
<section class="footer">
<div class="links">
<p><span id="solen"><a href="#">xxxx</a></span>  
<span id="solen"><a href="#">aaaa</a></span></p>
</div>
</section><br>
</footer>

<style>
.links {
text-align:centre;
display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```

And all the elements in your div tag will be aligned in centre irrespective of page size without hampering user experience

Comment: what about screen resize? is links displaying fine?